# Loading dates in the format 2019-12-25T00: 00: 00.000Z in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

How to upload data with the date format 2019-12-25T00: 00: 00.000Z to the mysql db? I use the str_to_date function.

```
load data infile 'C:/file.tsv' into table table terminated by '\t' lines terminated by'\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@var_datetime,  data1) set datetime = str_to_date(@var_datetime,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%f%Z');
```

I get an error. Error code: 1411. Invalid date and time value: "2019-12-25T00: 00: 00.000Z" for str_to_date function

Comment: I would be tempted to load it into a varchar and then manipulate it afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just remvove the percent sign before `Z`, so it is considered a litteral string

```
str_to_date(@var_datetime,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ')
```

Note that `%T` comes handy to shorten the time specifier:

```
str_to_date(@var_datetime, '%Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ')
```